# Webpack 2 can't find jquery autocomplete module

Tags: javascript, webpack-2

I have the following webpack config file:

```
const path = require('path');

const config = {
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: 'assets'
  },
  resolve: {
      modules: [
        './js',
        './js/jquery'
      ],
      alias: {
          'jquery': 'jquery/jquery-1.10.2.js',
          'jquery-ui': 'jquery/jquery-ui.js'
      }
  },
  entry: {
      settings : './js/model/settings.js'
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

On every build webpack ends with an error "Error: Can't resolve 'jquery-ui/autocomplete'" but jquery autocomplete is included in jquery ui. What is missing?